# How to plot a caret train object in a function

Tags: r, function, plot, r-caret

I want to write e function that trains a regression model using the `train` function of the `caret package` and plots the resampling profile. My problem  is that no plot is shown and no error is thrown. This should be a reproducible example:

```
trFun <- function(){
  library( caret )
  library( mlbench )
  data( BostonHousing )

  lmFit <- train(
    medv ~ .,
    data=BostonHousing,
    method="pls"
  )

  #trellis.par.set( caretTheme() )
  plot( lmFit )

  lmFit
}

fit <- trFun()

plot( fit )
```

So `plot( lmfit )` inside `trFun` doesn't plot anything, while `plot( fit )` outside the function does the plot. The `trellis.par.set( caretTheme() )` statement seems to be irrelevant.

My question is: how can I plot the resampling profile inside `trFun`?

This is the `sessionInfo()` output:

```
R version 3.4.3 (2017-11-30)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

Matrix products: default

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.4.3 tools_3.4.3    yaml_2.1.16
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
trFun <- function() {
  library( caret )
  library( mlbench )
  data( BostonHousing )

  lmFit <- train(
    medv ~ .,
    data=BostonHousing,
    method="pls"
  )

  #trellis.par.set( caretTheme() )
  print(plot( lmFit ))

  lmFit
}

trFun()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. It works, but probably the problem is that I had to `print` the plot as it is a `lattice` plot. Could you change the statements `p <- plot( lmFit )` and  `return(list(p,lmFit))` to `print( plot( lmFit ) )` and `lmFit` respectively? Then I will accept the answer.